# How to replace HTML elements like `<sup>X</sup>` by parentheticals like `(X)`?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, dom

I have HTML like this — `BLAH BLAH BLAH <sup>x</sup>` — inside a `<th>`.

I am trying to replace `<sup>x</sup>` by `(x)`.

These are all the different methods I have tried. `insideSup` is the letter.

```js
newText = $(tableRow).find("th").eq(tdIndex)
  .text().replace("<sup>(.*?)</sup>", " ") + "(" + insideSup + ")";
```

```js
newText = $(tableRow).find("th").eq(tdIndex)
  .html().replace("<sup>(.*?)</sup>", " ") + "(" + insideSup + ")";
```

```js
newText = $(tableRow).find("th").eq(tdIndex)
  .find("sup").html().replace("/<sup>/g", " ") + "(" + insideSup + ")";
```

```js
newText = $(tableRow).find("th").eq(tdIndex)
  .find("sup").html().replace("<sup>(.*?)</sup>", " ") + "(" + insideSup + ")";
```

```js
newText = $(tableRow).find("th").eq(tdIndex)
  .text().find("sup").html().replace("<sup>(.*?)</sup>", " ") + "(" + insideSup + ")";
```

Comment: None of your attempts actually contain regexes. `"<sup>(.*?)</sup>"` is a string, `/<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>/` is a regex; `"/<sup>/g"` is a string, `/<sup>/g` is a regex, and so on. `replace` matches strings _literally_.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the DOM available to you. You [don’t need regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4642212) at all. Just use the [`replaceWith` method](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith):

```js
$(tableRow).find("th").eq(tdIndex).find("sup")
  .replaceWith((_index, textContent) => `(${textContent})`);
```

Equivalently, without jQuery, assuming `tableRow` is an `HTMLTableRowElement`, using a [method with the same name](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith):

```js
tableRow.querySelectorAll("th")[tdIndex].querySelectorAll("sup")
  .forEach((sup) => sup.replaceWith(`(${sup.textContent})`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight-forward with just `String.replace()`;

```js
let target = document.querySelector("div");

// Store the text (not HTML) in the sup
let originalText = target.querySelector("sup").textContent;

// Replace the sup element with the original content of the sup, 
// surrounded by ()
target.textContent = target.innerHTML.replace("<sup>x</sup>", "(" + originalText + ")");
```

```html
<div>BLAH BLAH BLAH <sup>x</sup></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by replacing the `<sup>` and `</sup>` separately. You can do it by using `String.replace()` method as shown below.

```js
let text = "BLAH BLAH BLAH <sup>x</sup>";
let newText = text.replace("<sup>", "(").replace("</sup>", ")");
```